# Display records that have a match in a join query first

Tags: php, mysql, database, join

To simplify the problem down for the question, I have a **listings** table and a **listings_featured** table. The main **listings** tables holds the main data for all listings but the **listings_featured** table holds data for only listings which are featured.

I want to display listings ordered by whether they are featured or not first, meaning the rows which have a match when doing a LEFT or RIGHT JOIN should come first. How would I go about doing this with just one query rather than two?

**EDIT**

Also, is it possible to add a `WHERE` condition to the query that only applies to the **joined** records? For example, out of the featured listings, I only want the ones which have the condition `WHERE featured_end_date > now()` - this should only apply to the joined records. This is because the duration for which a listing is featured will be different to the actual expiry date of the listing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT l.*
FROM listings l
    LEFT JOIN listings_featured lf ON lf.lid = l.lid
WHERE lf.lid IS NULL OR lf.featured_end_date > now()
ORDER BY lf.lid IS NULL
```

`lf.lid IS NULL` is `FALSE` for all featured listings so while sorting they get put before other listings.

**EDIT**

Added WHERE condition

Comment: Thanks :) do you know if it's possible to attach a WHERE condition ONLY to joined records? (I've edited my post)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17058034/sql-display-records-matching-lookup-table-first-then-all-other-records

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is to use `ORDER BY` using one of the columns only available in the listings_featured table. Nulls should go to the bottom of the list.